# user has NOPASSWD privileges, sudo still asks for password

Tags: sudo

I am trying to allow a user `sudo` access to `NOPASSWD` but something seems to be overridding the config? First invocation of `sudo` asks for a password.

Here is the output of the users `sudo` permissions and trying to run a command as another user through `sudo`.

Am I missing something here?

```bash
╭─   ~ ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── with baudneo@ZoneMinder at  12:35:25 PM
╰─❯ sudo -l -U  baudneo
Matching Defaults entries for baudneo on ZoneMinder:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin, use_pty

User baudneo may run the following commands on ZoneMinder:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

╭─   ~ ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── with baudneo@ZoneMinder at  12:36:28 PM
╰─❯ groups
baudneo sudo

╭─   ~ ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── with baudneo@ZoneMinder at  12:36:09 PM
╰─❯ sudo -u www-data zmml_eventproc -E -e 1263 -m 7 -D -C /etc/zm/client.yml
Sorry, user baudneo is not allowed to execute '/usr/local/bin/zmml_eventproc -E -e 1263 -m 7 -D -C /etc/zm/client.yml' as www-data on ZoneMinder.localdomain.
```

Edit: Ubuntu 22.04 LXC, I am trying to run a python script as the www-data user, my permissions and sudo config seem correct.

Edit 2: It was a full disk issue, after making space on the disk the command runs as www-data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using and ii) explain what you want to do. It looks like you want to be able to run commands _as another user_, but you are only talking about the `baudneo` user here. Can you run `sudo zmml_eventproc -E -e 1263 -m 7 -D -C /etc/zm/client.yml` (without `-u www-data`)?

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1328457/432690). `sudo -l` prints `(ALL : ALL) ALL` after `(ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and this explains why `sudo` asks for password. I'm not sure why `user baudneo is not allowed to execute …` though. I wonder if `ZoneMinder` vs `ZoneMinder.localdomain` has anything to do with it.

Comment: Add the `Runas_Spec` which shall allow the `sudo -u www-data zmml_eventproc` command to your question, including the `Host_Alias`. It seems that instead of `ALL =` you actually have a host defenition (`ZoneMinder`) but use the `fqdn` flag so that this has to be `ZoneMinder.localdomain` instead (or just remove the flag, if that does not cause other problems, of course).

Comment: not a dupplicate, but see my answer here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395776/how-to-remote-execute-ssh-command-a-sudo-command-without-password/395781#395781

Answer (score 0):

So, the disk was almost full. After making space all is well.

Very strange symptom for a full disk.

Thanks to everyone for their time!